# QGIS server HTTP Post requests

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-server, http-post

I have a Python filter to handle a few endpoints to do some configuration and calculation. For that I use the HTTP-GET method. Now, I want to use HTTP-POST to send some data to the Python filter.

Here is my example Request:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=POST_TEST`

In the QGIS log file I can clearly see that the request is getting handled somehow:

`[1303][12:28:26] REMOTE_ADDR: 172.23.0.1
[1303][12:28:26] CONTENT_TYPE: application/json
[1303][12:28:26] HTTP_USER_AGENT: curl/7.47.0
[1303][12:28:26] QgsPostRequestHandler::parseInput
[1303][12:28:26] QgsHttpRequestHandler::readPostBody
[1303][12:28:26] length is: 35
[1303][12:28:26] {"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}
[1303][12:28:26] inserting pair SERVICE // POST_TEST into the parameter map
[1303][12:28:26] Error at line 1, column 1: error occurred while parsing element.`

But it is not possible to access the parsed information. I tried it with the same code-snipped which I use to retrieve information from a HTTP-GET Request:

`request = self.serverInterface().requestHandler()
params = request.parameterMap()
service = params.get('SERVICE', '')
body = request.body()`

Well, I think that there are simple no bindings for Python to handle a HTTP-POST Request?

Version:

- Apache/2.4.10
- load library /usr/lib/qgispython (2.18.4)

Comment: Does the service GetCapabilities response say that it can handle HTTP POST?

Comment: Actually not, but i activated for example WFS in the *.qgs file. I can also do geatFeature-Requests. Maybe the problem lies in the log `[1303][12:28:26] Error at line 1, column 1: error occurred while parsing element.`

Comment: But that would mean, that my curl request is not correct.

Comment: Well for the WFS i can see the POST section. But i don't want to do a WMS or WFS request, it is completely independent from that.

Comment: AFAIK, http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi? defines the service end-point to one or more OGC services, so you should only be able to use the service interfaces supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, probably I found a workaround which is really bad. I found out, that the best way to get my information is to mix normal text with json. Let me show you what I mean.
`curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/text" -X POST -d 'SERVICE=POST_TEST&json={"test":"test", "test2":[1,2,3,4], "test3":{"test4":"test5"}}' 'http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?' -H "Accept: application/text"`

What does QGIS do with the request body? It still produce one error message and then a parameter list.
`Error at line 1, column 1: error occurred while parsing element.
[832][08:53:52] inserting pair SERVICE // POST_TEST into the parameter map
[832][08:53:52] inserting pair JSON // {"test":"test", "test2":[1,2,3,4], "test3":{"test4":"test5"}} into the parameter map`

The parameter list is now accessible by the parameterMap.
`request = self.serverInterface().requestHandler()
params = request.parameterMap()`

By the way
`request = self.serverInterface().requestHandler()
body = request.body()`

is always empty....

Ok back to the workaround. Now I can check first for the SERVICE parameter to pull the rest of the params to the right function and than I can parse the value for the json parameter.
`requestBody = json.loads(params.get('JSON', ''))`

`{u'test': u'test', u'test3': {u'test4': u'test5'}, u'test2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}`

Well, as I said in the beginning I don't like this kind of workaround!